# Visual Studio 2017 msvc vs nvcc __cplusplus macro mismatch

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, visual-studio-2017, thrust

I am using Visual Studio 2017, platform toolset v141 and CUDA Toolkit 9.2.
I have noticed that move constructor and move assignment are not present when compiling **thrust::device_vector** with nvcc. The reason is a condition which checks the value of the **__cplusplus** macro in the Thrust lib.

As explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2017), I set C++ Language Standard to **/std:c++17** and set additionally **/Zc:__cplusplus** in order to have the macro defined correctly in msvc, i.e., **201703**.
However for files compiled by nvcc the macro is set to **199711**.

I have created a simple case that reproduces the issue.

test.cuh:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
void test();
```

test.cu:

```
#include "test.cuh"
void test()
{
    std::cout << "CU  file: " << __cplusplus << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "test.cuh"
int main()
{
    test();
    std::cout << "CPP file: " << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
CU  file: 199711
CPP file: 201703
```

I am looking for a solution that is applicable also to CMake with FindCUDA.

Comment: For what it is worth, this doesn't happen with CUDA 9.2 on linux. Have you checked the verbose output from the build and that nvcc is really getting the `-std` option and is not ignoring it? nvcc only supports c++11 and c++14 as far as I know

Comment: If I set the /Zc:__cplusplus flag in project properties: C/C+/Host/Additional Compiler Options, then __cplusplus macro is 201402 when compiling with nvcc. This would already solve my issue, but still there is a mismatch. How can I achieve this via CMake?

Comment: I have managed to set __cplusplus to 201402 when compiling with nvcc by passing -Xcompiler=/Zc:__cplusplus

Comment: If that is your solution, would you find adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to set __cplusplus to 201402 by passing **-Xcompiler /Zc:__cplusplus** to nvcc. Since nvcc only supports up to C++14 this is probably the best I can get with CUDA 9.2.